# Angular incorrect behaviours with custom directives

Tags: angularjs, controls, directive

Below is my issue
Issue with my custom control code.I have created a two custom control

```
<pv-Show-Box></pv-Show-Box>
<pv-Hello>Praveen</pv-Hello>
both are working fine but <pv-show-Box> is not working when it is in reverse order
like 
<pv-Hello>Praveen</pv-Hello>
<pv-Show-Box></pv-Show-Box>

mumodule.directive('pvShowBox', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div><input type="text" ng-model="txtfieldData" ></input> {{ txtfieldData }}</div>',
        replace: true
    }
});


mumodule.directive('pvHello', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<span ng-transclude>Hello </span>',
        replace: true
    };
});
```

Any idea??

Comment: What is the error, Have you seen the console of the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a small problem in your code you are using ng-transclude but you have not mentioned transclude property in directive so just change below directive definition and it will work both ways

```
 mumodule.directive('pvHello', function () {
              return {
                  restrict: 'E',
                  transclude:true,
                  template: '<span ng-transclude>Hello </span>',
                  replace: true
              };
          });
```

Comment: Yes, This is  my fault, but could you please explain why same code is working when i am using pvShowBox custom control first then PvHello but same it is not working in reverse order PvHello then pvShowBox

Comment: this is because if your declare pvhello first then angular will throw an error in ng-translude  and furthur angular interpolation would not work but if you declare revere then pvshow executes first and interpolation works as expected .Hope u understand